# Concat Pandas DF with CSV File

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, dask

I want to concat 2 data-frames into one df and save as one csv considering that the first dataframe is in csv file and huge so i dont want to load it in memory. I tried the df.to_csv with append mode but it doesnt behave like df.concat in regards to different columns (comparing and combining columns). Anyone knows how to concat a csv and a df ? Basically csv and df can have different columns so the output csv should have only one header along with all columns and proper respective rows.

Comment: see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas

Comment: upload/embed sample datasets and expected output. then we can suggest the code

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Dask DataFrame](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html) to do this operation lazily. It'll load your data into memory, but do so in small chunks. Make sure to keep the partition size (blocksize) reasonable -- based on your overall memory capacity.

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf1 = dd.read_csv("data1.csv", blocksize=25e6)
ddf2 = dd.read_csv("data2.csv", blocksize=25e6)

new_ddf = dd.concat([ddf1, ddf2])

new_ddf.to_csv("combined_data.csv")
```

API docs: [`read_csv`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html#dask.dataframe.read_csv), [`concat`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.data), [`to_csv`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.to_csv.html#dask.dataframe.to_csv)